Logitech touchpad events showing in libinput but have no desktop effect
I have solaar (1.1.13) showing the following information for a wireless touchpad, however the touchpad is ignored by the desktop environment (Wayland on Ubuntu 22.04).
It just stopped functioning a few days ago with no clear reason.
Wireless Touchpad
     Device path  : /dev/hidraw4
     WPID         : 4011
     Codename     : Wireless Touch
     Kind         : touchpad
     Protocol     : HID++ 2.0
     Report Rate : 8ms
     Serial number: DCBF0037
     Model ID:      000000000000
     Unit ID:       00000000
                 0: RQM 32.00.B0012
                 1: BL  02.00.B0001
                 2: 72
     The power switch is located on the base.
     Supports 20 HID++ 2.0 features:
         0: ROOT                   {0000} V0     
         1: FEATURE SET            {0001} V0     
         2: FEATURE INFO           {0002} V0     
         3: DEVICE FW VERSION      {0003} V0     
            Firmware: Firmware RQM 32.00.B0012 4011
            Firmware: Bootloader BL  02.00.B0001 4011
            Firmware: Hardware  72 
            Unit ID: 00000000  Model ID: 000000000000  Transport IDs: {}
         4: DEVICE NAME            {0005} V0     
            Name: Wireless Touchpad
            Kind: touchpad
         5: BATTERY STATUS         {1000} V0     
            Battery: 90%, discharging, next level 50%.
         6: WIRELESS DEVICE STATUS {1D4B} V0     
         7: unknown:1DF3           {1DF3} V0    hidden 
         8: REPROG CONTROLS        {1B00} V0     
         9: unknown:1F03           {1F03} V0    hidden 
        10: VERTICAL SCROLLING     {2100} V0     
            Roller type: normal touch pad
            Ratchet per turn: 18
            Scroll lines: 0
        11: HI RES SCROLLING       {2120} V0     
            Hi-res scrolling disabled
            Hi-res scrolling multiplier: 8
            Scroll Wheel High Resolution (saved): True
            Scroll Wheel High Resolution        : False
        12: MOUSE POINTER          {2200} V0     
            DPI: 1000
            Acceleration: low
            Override OS ballistics
            No vertical tuning, standard mice
        13: DFUCONTROL LEGACY      {00C0} V0     
        14: unknown:1E80           {1E80} V0    hidden 
        15: TOUCHPAD RAW XY        {6100} V0    hidden 
        16: TOUCHPAD FW ITEMS      {6010} V0     
        17: TOUCHPAD SW ITEMS      {6011} V0     
        18: unknown:1E00           {1E00} V0    hidden 
        19: REPROG CONTROLS V2     {1B01} V0     
     Has 7 reprogrammable keys:
         0: Application Switcher       => Application Switcher          mse
         1: Left Button                => Left Click                    mse, reprogrammable
         2: Right Button               => Right Click                   mse, reprogrammable
         3: Back Button                => Mouse Back Button             mse
         4: Forward Button             => Mouse Forward Button          mse
         5: Show Desktop               => Show Desktop                  mse
         6: Analog HScroll             => HorzScrollNoRepeatSet         mse
     Battery: 90%, discharging, next level 50%.

I have had a similar issue few years ago, a few Ubuntu releases back, solved by upgrading. However I have this issue also with the latest version of solaar this time.
Of course I've already tried all the obvious things voodoo ― replacing batteries, restarting, re-pairing, using a different USB port ― several times.
What should be my next steps after the following?
diagnostic outputs from libinput:
$ libinput list-devices
Device:           Logitech Wireless Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event27
Group:            6
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             95x64mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a

Crucially, using sudo libinput debug-events I can see that every finger motion and every button click on the touchpad do accordingly translate to a POINTER_MOTION and POINTER_BUTTON event, same as when fiddling a plain mouse connected to the same machine. Only, the plain mouse moves the cursor and makes clicks happen, whereas with the touchpad there's no effect other than its events showing up in the wayland debug trace.

this has all the things you can try: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Logitech_Unifying_Receiver   but it could be a wayland issue/bug :P

Thanks. Following there I tried using https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops in place of solaar. Just like solaar, it detects the logitech receiver and the logitech trackpad, but the touchpad still has no effect as a pointing device, just the same. So I'll be looking at the Wayland diagnostics commands from https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/tools.html. I have updated the question with the relevant outputs from those libinput input device debugging commands.

would it work, if you'd switch to a X11 Session - just for testing ?

Seems that touchpads need to be enabled, they don't operate as a pointing device if they are not set to be allowed, in the following system settings menu:

That's all.
